# What is the best way to handle redirects in WordPress using Timber and Twig?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, twig, timber

I would like to redirect the author, category and tag pages to my home page.
In Yoast SEO I have set these pages to not be indexed, but I want them to actually redirect permanently to the home page.

I tried the following code in functions.php but it had no effect:

```
// Redirect all author archives to the website's about page
add_filter('author_link', 'ehi_author_link');
function ehi_author_link()
{
    return home_url('home');
}
```

or

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_custom_disable_author_page');

function my_custom_disable_author_page() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( is_author() ) {
        // Redirect to homepage, set status to 301 permenant redirect.
        // Function defaults to 302 temporary redirect.
        wp_redirect(get_option('home'), 301);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use redirects at the server level in `.htaccess`?

Comment: I am using NGINX so no .htaccess. I would rather handle this through WordPress anyway.

Comment: I have ended up using a plugin (Redirects) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way. Using `home_url` will directly get your homepage url.

```
function redirect_author() {
    if ( is_author() || is_category() || is_tag() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_author' );
```

Comment: What you posted is the same as what I posted above, except not using global $wp_query;

Are you saying this should work usually, or it should work if I remove that?